# How to get rid of raw onion smell while doing Gojju when forgotten to fry the onions

Tags: indian-cuisine, onions, smell

I forgot to fry the onions before grinding it. Now I have added the ground raw onions with masala to make semi liquid sambar(gojju), how do I get rid of raw smell? Should I keep heating the Bindi gojju?

Comment: Sambar and Gojju are very different things - If I recall, gojju is thick and tamarind based, and sambar is lentil based. The 'standard' Sambar dosen't have raw onions in its spices either - most people use a dry spice mix. Could you clarify what exactly this dish is, and how its cooked?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, edited the word sambar. I agree what you said is right.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, a combination of acid (lemon juice/tomatoes/tamarind paste) and heat(temperature) is used to cut the taste of raw onions. You will need to continue frying the raw onion and masala mixture until it separates from the oil, which is a good indicator of the doneness of the onions as well as the spices.
If you follow this route of cooking the onions after pureeing them, you would also not want to roast the spices before grinding them, and instead fry them all together at this stage.

Answer (score -1):

Adding fried shallots or caramelized onion may help.